# Using AES_DECRYPT with SELECT *

Tags: mysql, select, encryption, aes

Is it possible to select all records and decrypt them using the asterisk with the AES_DECRYPT function? This is what I want to be able to do:

```
SELECT AES_DECRYPT(*, SOMESTATICKEY) FROM some_table
```

EDIT: I guess I should clarify my question since I know what I'm asking doesn't work. What I want to know is if there is any other way syntactically or functionally to do this.

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: It doesn't work and I get the general "You have an error in your SQL syntax" message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a look at this link  about  `SELECT` Syntax for mysql
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html
 You can see that after The `SELECT` verb the command is expecting a `select_expr` or a list of `select_expr`

which means you have to issue commands in this form.

```
SELECT AES_DECRYPT(Field1, SOMESTATICKEY),
       AES_DECRYPT(Field2, SOMESTATICKEY),
       AES_DECRYPT(Field3, SOMESTATICKEY)
FROM some_table
```

Moreover, AES_DECRYPT() function is expecting a string as its first parameter not a list.

So the answer is clearly No